# Conroe stepping

Tags: cpu, xeon

I have two Intel Xeon 3050 CPUs which apparently have different stepping, I'd like to know which is better but am having difficulty finding specific stepping level info.

sSPEC: SL9TY
CPUID: 06F6h
Core stepping: B2
PCB ID: 001

sSPEC: SLABZ
CPUID: 06F6h
Core stepping: L2
PCB ID: 003

I have read that one has the Allendale core with the native 2MB L2 cache and the other has the Conroe core with the 4MB L2 cache halved.
I'm not overly fussed about overclocking these processors.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to know which is better

They are identical from a performance point of view.

> I have read that one has the Allendale core with the native 2MB L2
>   cache and the other has the Conroe core with the 4MB L2 cache halved.
>   I'm not overly fussed about overclocking these processors.

What you have read is incorrect.  Only specific processors which have the Conroe 
core had more then 2MB of L2 cache.  In the case of the **Intel Xeon 3050**, both Allendale and Conroe, have only 2 MB of L2 cache.  The processors are **identical** in every possible way except the die size was reduced by 32 mm in the Conroe variant.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Additionally,

> Do all processor numbers have the same sSpec?
>   The same processor number can have different sSpecs. When a processor stepping change occurs, a new sSpec generates for that stepping. The same stepping level can also have more than one sSpec associated with it.

## Sources:

- [Core-based Xeons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors#.22Allendale.22_.2865_nm.29)
- [How to Find Your sSpec Number for Intel® Processors](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000007490/processors.html)